# changing the coordinates of a python window

Tags: python, graphics, graph, tkinter

I'm creating a Tkinter window of size 500x500 that draws a graph on a canvas widget

I need to make it so that the coordinates of lower left-hand corner is 0,0, and the coordinates of the upper right hand corner is 500,500.  And I think I might need to do that for the canvas object as well (is that true?)

How do I do this?  I haven't been able to find a clear answer when I searched for it online.

Answer (score 0):

The scitools package has a class called [CanvasCoords](http://scitools.googlecode.com/hg/doc/api/html/TkGUI.html#scitools.TkGUI.CanvasCoords) which may be what you are after.

The main author of scitools is Prof. Hans Langtangen.  He discusses coordinate systems in section "11.3.2 Cordinate Systems" of his (IMHO) excellent book "Python Scripting for Computational Science"  It's on page 552-555 in my version. You can see page 553-555  (you don't miss much on page 552) on the [google books sample pages](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=YEoiYr4H2A0C&lpg=PR6&ots=owqTFJYzjZ&dq=Python%20Scripting%20for%20Computational%20Science,%203rd%20edition,%202nd%20printing&pg=PA553#v=onepage&q=Python%20Scripting%20for%20Computational%20Science,%203rd%20edition,%202nd%20printing&f=false).